# how to fire swipe in JEST with React-testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

```
   const Comp = () => (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router>
                <FeedWrapper {...props} />
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    );
    const component = renderer.create(<Comp />);
    const { findByRole } = render(<Comp />);
    const swipeHandlerElement = findByRole("testingSwipeHandler");
    fireEvent.click(swipeHandlerElement);//not working
    let tree = component.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
```

I am using the Jest library, how to fire swipe in JEST with React-testing-library?

Comment: Can you share the `FeedWrapper` component, where you are using the role attribute?

Comment: something like that
class FeedWrapper extends React.PureComponent {

render(){

return (<SwipeHandler role="testingSwipeHandler"

tabs={headerItems || defaultTab}

match={match}

history={history}></SwipHandler>)

}

}

Comment: You are using `SwipeHandler`, and It looks like `Swipehandler` is not using role property in children. If it is a third-party library you need to check if it supports role prop or not.

Comment: Did you get this working? I need to swipe too.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to simulate swipe in `react-native-testing-library`, but one can use `fireEvent` and specify the swipe callback to "simulate" the gesture.

For example, given this component:

```js
const App = () => (
  <MySwipeComponent onSwipeLeft={swipeLeftCallback}>
    <Text>Swipe Me</Text>
  </MySwipeComponent>
);
```

One can use the following to "simulate" the outcome of a swipe action.

```js
render(<App />)
fireEvent(screen.getByText('Swipe Me'), 'onSwipeLeft')
```

For more info, check out [this answer](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library/issues/918#issuecomment-1041236315). For the general usage of `fireEvent`, refer to [the doc](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/api/#fireevent).