# How to simulate Swiping with Jest and React Testing Library?

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a React component (this one: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/#swipeable) and on mobile when you swipe from the edge it opens the drawer. I tested it manually and it works. I want to test that using Jest and React Testing Library.

I checked the documentation and tried to research the question online, but I found no answer to my question. Here are similar questions on Stack Overflow, also with no answers to them.

- [React/Jest - How to simulate touch "swipe" event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72239312/react-jest-how-to-simulate-touch-swipe-event)
- [how to fire swipe in JEST with React-testing-library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70844307/how-to-fire-swipe-in-jest-with-react-testing-library)

So, how to simulate a swipe gesture using Jest and React Testing Library?